# HTML5 Shiv not working in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, html5shiv

I'm sure this is probably something really simple but I can't see the woods for the trees. For some reason HTML5 Shiv isn't loading. In IE7 my HTML5 tags nav, header, footer don't perform as expected. What am I missing?

Preview: http://dyingtounderstand.thecreativecollective.com.au/

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just checked your site in IE7 and it is loading the shiv, its likely to be a CSS layout problem in IE7.

[image: shiv loaded in ie7]

As a sanity check try styling the `header` and `footer` elements with a `background-color` just to see if you can target those elements.

Then work out why IE7 is messing up your layout.

Comment: It turns out I had some a dodgy clearfix definition which IE7 didn't like. I stripped this out and replaced it with something more valid. Then all good. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help a fellow developer once again! :)